# How can we set Java classpath in shell script?

Tags: java, shell, unix, classpath, java-home

I need a help with this concept. I searched several threads in this forum but none matched my problem.

I write two java classes and a shell script. I zip them into a folder and send it to another person who does not know java. He would just unpack and run the shell script.

The person will extract the code anywhere in his machine. So now the shell script should do the following.

1. Check if Java is installed properly
2. If so, set the java class path to the folder where the java classes are present.
3. Check java version. This is achieved in the script. So no problem
4. Compile and run.

My zip file would contain App.java, Message.java, MyCodeExecution.sh.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:.

    echo $CLASSPATH

    VER=`java -version 2>&1 | grep "java version" | awk '{print $3}' 
    | tr   -d \" | awk '{split($0, array, ".")} END{print array[2]}'`
    if [[ $VER -gt 6 ]]; then
        echo "Java version is greater than 1.6."
    else
        echo "Java version is lower than 1.6."
    fi

    javac App.java
    javac Message.java
    java App
```

This is my code for Message and App.java

```
  package com.demo;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;

    /**
     * This class creates two instances of same class and performs message
     * transmission.
     * 
     */
    public class App {
        final static String initTurn = "initiator";
        final static String receiverTurn = "receiver";



        public static void main(String[] args) {
            App app = new App();
            InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(System.in); // Input reader for messages
            InputStreamReader totalMessages = new InputStreamReader(System.in); // Input reader to get total number of
                                                                                // messages
            BufferedReader br = null;
            Message initiator = new Message(); /* Instance for initiator who initiates the message */
            Message receiver = new Message(); /* Instance for receiver who receives and re-sends the message. */

            String initMessage = null; /* Message got from the initiator */
            String recvMessage = null; /* Message to be sent back to initiator by receiver */
            String turn = initTurn; /* Turn to send message by initiator or receiver. */
            try {

                /*
                 * This snippet is implemented to give option of sending n number of messages
                 * and receive it. User can choose to transmit total number of messages
                 */
                int c = 0;
                 System.out.println("How many messages do you wish to transmit? ");

                br = new BufferedReader(totalMessages);
                c = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

                /* br object is reset for receiving messages from user. */
                br = null;
                br = new BufferedReader(r);
                for (int counter = 1; counter <= c;) { /*
                                                         * Message transmission stops when initiator reach the transmission
                                                         * limit
                                                         */
                    if (initTurn.equals(turn)) {
                        System.out.println("\nInitiator... Please type your message:\n ");
                        if (counter == c) {
                             System.out.println("This would be the last message which you may sent and receive.\n");

                        }
                        /* Receiving message as input by initiator. */
                        initMessage = br.readLine();
                        turn = receiverTurn; /*
                                                 * turn is set to receiver that is transmission turn is now given to
                                                 * receiver.
                                                 */
                        initiator.setMessage(initMessage);
                    } else if (receiverTurn.equals(turn)) {
                        /* Receiver gets message from Initiator */
                        receiver.setMessage(initiator.getMessage());
                        recvMessage = receiver.getMessage();
                        /* Receiver re-sends the message to the initiator with the message counter. */
                         System.out.println("\nMessage received by Initiator from Receiver is: ' " +
                         recvMessage
                         + "'. Message counter " + counter);

                        if (counter == c) {
                            System.out.println("\nMessage transmission limit over. See you again.");
                        }
                        turn = initTurn; /*
                                             * turn is set to receiver that is transmission turn is now given to initiator.
                                             */
                        counter++;
                    }
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (br != null) {
                    try {
                        br.close();
                    } catch (IOException ie) {
                        ie.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if (totalMessages != null) {
                    try {
                        totalMessages.close();
                    } catch (IOException ie) {
                        ie.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if (r != null) {
                    try {
                        r.close();
                    } catch (IOException ie) {
                        ie.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    class Message {

        String message;

        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the class path to the current folder, in your shell script, like this:
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:.
That way it will be able to find the Player class on the same folder.

Comment: I do not know what is the class path of the java in another machine? Is it possible to write shell commands to find the java environment variable in an machine?

Comment: Yes. Class path variable will be called CLASSPATH in a linux environment and you can use it by adding a $ sign just before the name like so: echo $CLASSPATH

Comment: In the line above, export is setting the CLASSPATH variable to whatever it was and it's also adding "." to the classpath. in Linux the dot sign "."  refers to the current folder.

Comment: echo $CLASSPATH is not printing anything. I tried %CLASSPATH, %CLASSPATH%, $CLASSPATH. but none of them give the result.  I tried giving $(which java) but it prints the java.exe path. Can you please help? I am not a unix programmer but I have to give these commands to produce a script.

Comment: It should work now with your changes. Could you please post the source code from both App.java and Message.java so I can give it a try on my machine?

Comment: Ok, now I understand what's going on. When you specify a package in java, it is expected that the package will reflect the folder hierarchy where the .java file is located. Since you have specified the package as com.demo you need to have a file structure like com/demo/App.java. 
Honestly the easiest thing you can do to make this work is to remove the package declaration on the first line of App.java. 
Also, on MyCodeExecution.sh you need to remove the line javac Message.java since you do not have such file (message class has been declared within App.java).